# How to make the client side start on port 8080?

Tags: node.js, port

I recently almost finished developing an application and I am required to make the client side start on port 8080 . I use `npm start` in `Node.js`to start the project, and the client side by `http-server` ,and I am not allowed to use sockets. When I searched for this I saw that the answers was by using sockets .

I appreciate any help or guides.

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far? Do you want to run a web server on 8080 from nodejs?

Comment: @IsuruPathirana searched about this wuestion in the net but all I found was by using  sockets and I must not use sockets, so I tried to ask here to get some guides or materials to read that can help me. Regarding running the server side ,it should start at port 9000 ,but that I managed to do it using server.listen(9000) in javascript .. the problem is that I don't know how to start the client on port 8080?

Comment: can you post the error message here , when you try to listen on port 8080.

Comment: @user8244016 Well basically you can use the same thing to spin up a web server on port 8080. You can use server.listen(8080). If you are getting any error please post them here as Aman has suggested.

Comment: @AmanArora there is no error message , and also I do not want to listen to port 8080 for server , server is running on port 9000 and I want to run the client on port 8080 but I don't know how

Comment: @IsuruPathirana as I told Aman I don't get any errors , I want to start server on port 9000 (this I succeeded to do ), and start client on port 8080 (this I don't know how to do)

Comment: @user8244016 What are you using for your front end ? (tech stack). Also is there a reason you want your server and client code to run on different servers?